# What can stop a bash for loop from the inside?

Tags: bash

I'm running through a bunch of data like this:

```
for id in `cat ids.list` ; do echo $id ; bin/migrate.pl --id $id ; done
```

I'm having a problem where after a couple hundred $ids the migrate.pl script dies with a timeout error from my backend (though I'm not sure I believe the error message).

But when the migrate.pl script dies, the whole bash for-loop stops too.  I would expect bash to continue on to the migrate.pl with next $id.  How can the script be killing for for-loop?  I find that surprising, and I'm not able to reproduce it with any other mechanism, and I wonder if it might be related to my problem.

Comment: Perhaps you have `set -e` turned on, which causes bash to exit whenever an simple command (such as the Perl script invocation in your case) returns a non-zero exit code. To see the current value, run `shopt -o errexit`; to turn it off, run `shopt -u -o errexit` or `set +e`.

Comment: This will try to buffer the output of the [tag:cat]

Comment: It's not set -e:

   $ shopt -o errexit
   errexit         off

and if I replace the script that does nothing but die, then loop continues as expected. So that's not it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will try to buffer the output `cat ids.list` and likely get an overflow for large files. You should instead do something like

```
while read -r line; do
    for id in $line; do
        echo "$id"
        bin/migrate.pl --id "$id"
    done
done < ids.list
```

Comment: The file is only 750 items, 9k of data, but this approach solved the problem, thanks!  I don't understand though--where is the buffering/overflow going on?

Comment: @KevinG. Any time you do `for something in $(command)` it will attempt to buffer the output of `$(command)`, do word-splitting on it, and loop over each token in a string like "id1 id2 id3 ..."